# DAX Formula for Number of Matches Won/Drawn/Lost

Tags: excel, pivot, dax, powerpivot, measure

I am trying to create several DAX measures in Power Pivot for determining how many matches have been won, drawn and lost by each team in my football table.

I currently have custom DAX formulas for these columns:

Overall Played: `=CALCULATE(COUNT(match_result[club_id]), match_main[status_id]=2)`

Home Goals: `=CALCULATE(SUM(match_result[goal]), match_result[home_team]=1)`

Away Goals: `=CALCULATE(SUM(match_result[goal]), match_result[home_team]<>1)`

Overall Won: ?

Overall Drawn: ?

Overall Lost: ?

This is what my pivot table looks like so far:

[image: Pivot Table]

This is my relational Data Model structure:

[image: Data Model]

Each `match_id` has two rows in `match_result` as the home and away side are stored as separate records. The `home_team` field is a boolean value to determine if the `club_id` was the home side for the `match_id` in that row. The `goal` field records the number of goals that the `club_id` scored in that `match_id`.

Here is my workbook: https://www.excelforum.com/attachments/excel-formulas-and-functions/658773d1579562963-adding-new-columns-in-power-pivot-using-dax-formulas-attachment.zip.

Comment: Can you post sample data. Maybe as a pbix file?

Comment: I couldn't find a way of saving it as a pbix file, but I have attached my workbook.